# Synaptic update: should I accept changes to system config files such as /etc/lsb-release?

Tags: upgrade, synaptic

I'm running Linux Mint 17.3 (Rosa). I initialised updates using Synaptic. I asked for whatever recommended updates were on the list, plus `lxc-template`. Now I've got the following dialogue box:

```
Replace configuration file '/etc/lsb-release'?

The configuration file /etc/lsb-release was modified (by you or by a
script). An updated version is shipped in this package. If you want
to keep your current version, say 'Keep', otherwise it will be replaced.
Do you want to replace the current file, by installing the
new version from the package maintainers?
```

According to http://linux.die.net/man/1/lsb_release , this file is used for a command called `lsb_release` which checks the version of Linux being used. And I worry that if I get this wrong I may get mysterious errors in package management in the future.

The message also gives a diff of the file. It wants to change it from Linux Mint 17.3 to Ubuntu 14.04.

I've never manually changed this file, and I don't know what might have changed it in the background (in such a way that Synaptic thinks it might not be legit).

What's going on, and what should I do? I can think of two possibilities:

- Someone changed a package in the Debian repo, but forgot that the package is used by Mint (and Debian) as well as Ubuntu. This would also explain why it thinks it's a conflict, since the package in question would have expected it to already be on Ubuntu (just a slightly earlier version). In this case, I should keep the file set to Mint.
- Linux maintainers have decided that Mint and Ubuntu are now so similar that they will no longer be distinguished; the Mint version of the file is deprecated, and anything that tries to parse it may stop working in the future. Admittedly it does seem unlikely they would do this while still going to the trouble of tracking minor version numbers. If this is true then I should let it change to Ubuntu.
- Or another reason entirely?

I also got a very similar situation with `/etc/issue` and `/etc/issue.net`. In both cases I decided the files probably weren't important, and left them on Mint. Needless to say, I have no idea how many other conflicts like this I'll get when I continue with the upgrade.

Is this a known bug?